Is it really a good idea to learn to enumerate German adpositions taking the accusative and other cases?
I'm currently freshing up my German knowledge and I remember in school we were taught to remember and recite "für-um-durch-gegen-entlang-bis-ohne-wider", which are adpositions that take the accusative case. Furthermore "entlang" when used as an postposition.
My suspicion is that it would be more efficient to remember this the other way around, that is for each and every adposition learn which case they take (along with their meaning). Or even learn them together with a feminine, masculine, neuter and plural noun in definite form (or just the article).
Is my suspicion correct or is there some point in those recitations?
Maybe this isn't specific to German prepositions, but maybe other situations as well even if I can't come up with any other.

I was also taught to memorise German prepositions (and postpositions) for the accusative and the dative, and the six most common ones for the genitive. (The entire list of prepositions with the genitive is rather daunting.) It's useful when writing, but if you want to benefit from it while speaking, you need to reserve some "mental bandwidth" just to get the cases and morphology of articles, pronouns and adjectives right. This takes some effort, but if you have the chance to spend some time in a German-speaking country, this gets automated after a few weeks.
Nowadays, I would no longer recommend using only this approach. You can use a digital flashcard system such as Anki to store lots of phrases with cloze tests, such as the following:

Darf der Paketdienst das Päckchen einfach vor [...] Tür stellen?

As a learner, you need to figure out what word to fill in in the gap. (Solution: "... vor die Tür...".) If you like, the flash card's "solution side" can also briefly explain why the solution is correct. (E.g. "vor + Akkusativ: wohin?" so you understand why it should be the accusative.)
The idea is to expose yourself to hundreds of examples and thereby "absorb" the rules without learning them by rote. But if you know the lists of prepositions by heart, you can also tell yourself, "Ah, 'vor' can have either the accusative or the dative, depending on whether the phrase answers the question 'wohin?' or 'wo?', and here it's 'wohin?'". So I wouldn't discard those lists after all.

Yeah, I use anki, but then the question arises how many hundred of examples you'd need to grok the rules rather than just memorizing the answers? But what is the benefit of these lists of adpositions to learn?

@skyking How many example sentences you need has probably never been quantified by any studies. It's also a bit of a red herring because Anki should not be your main source of exposure to the language; it's a secondary tool to reinforce what you learn through other means (reading, listening, language classes, ...). The benefit of the lists is a kind of recognition in the sense of "Ah, yes, that's one of the prepositions that takes the accusative."

Another question is how to formulate those gap-questions for the two-way prepositions.

@skyking I think that is a separate question. And why would that be difficult?
